# What are the states in Biztalk Server

Tags: sql-server, biztalk

Recently I found out that the nState column in the BizTalkMsgBoxDb.Instances tells something about the state of the BizTalk artifact.

I already know now that nState=4 tells me that it is suspended (resumable) and nState=32 tells me that it is suspended (non-resumable). Is there an overview of all the possible states in BizTalk Server? At the moment I use this query for orchestrations for example:

```
SELECT o.uidGUID, o.nvcName AS Name, COUNT(*) as Count, i.nState,
    CASE i.nState
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Ready To Run'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Active'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Suspended Resumable'
    WHEN 8 THEN 'Dehydrated'
    WHEN 16 THEN 'Completed With Discarded Messages'
    WHEN 32 THEN 'Suspended Non-Resumable'
    END as State
    FROM [BizTalkMsgboxDb].dbo.[Instances] AS i WITH (NOLOCK)
    JOIN [BizTalkMgmtDb].dbo.[bts_Orchestration] AS o WITH (NOLOCK) ON i.uidServiceID = o.uidGUID
    GROUP BY o.uidGUID, o.nvcName, i.nState;
```

Are there any more states, and is it possible to get them for more artifacts together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the mappings we use:

- 1 : Started
- 2 : Completed
- 3 : Terminated
- 4 : Suspended
- 5 : ReadyToRun
- 6 : Active
- 8 : Dehydrated
- 16: CompletedWithDiscardedMessages
- 32: SuspendedNonResumable
- 64: InBreakpoint

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! If you can tell me that these are all the possible states then this could be the answer I am looking for, for now, I leave the question open a little longer.

Comment: And another thing, I found somewhere else that 2 was active, while you say 6 is. What are your resources, or is it just your long time of experience?

Comment: It is what we are using since BizTalk 2006 in our dashboard product.  Haven't come across any other states.  The 2 is completed, as far as I know, but it should be easy to double check.  (just don't have the time today)